# Transfer Characteristics of an EMOSFET

Tags: mosfet

An enhancement mode Mosfet's current-voltage equation in saturation mode is given by:
$$I_D =  \frac{\mu C_{ox}L}{2W}(V_{GS}-V_{th})^2$$

The graph:

[image]

**My question**:
I studied that the transfer characteristics can be obtained as long a \$V_D > 0\$. However, isn't it incorrect to just assume that the MOSFET is in saturation?

Comment: The formula should be MU * Cox * W /L ......

Answer (score 1):

The necessary condition for an NMOS to be in saturation region is:
V<sub>DS</sub> > V<sub>GS</sub> - V<sub>TH</sub>
or V<sub>DS</sub> + V<sub>TH</sub> > V<sub>GS</sub>

You can see the catch here. If you get your V<sub>GS</sub> too high, you will be in triode region.

I remember a problem in "Design of analog CMOS integrated circuits" by Behzad Razavi, in which he asks how transfer characteristics will change if V<sub>DS</sub> is low. Give it a read.